# MongoDB - Querying performance for over 10 million records

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, nosql

First of all: I already read a lot of post according to MongoDB query performance, but I didn't find any good solution.

Inside the collection, the document structure looks like:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535c4f1984af556ae798d629"),
    "point" : [
        -4.372925494081455,
        41.367710205649544
    ],
    "location" : [
        {
            "x" : -7.87297955453618,
            "y" : 73.3680160842939
        },
        {
            "x" : -5.87287143362673,
            "y" : 73.3674043270052
        }
    ],
    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1781389600000")
}
```

My collection already has an index:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({timestamp:-1})
```

Query looks like:

```js
db.collection.find({ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : 1380520800000 , "$lte" : 1380546000000}})
```

Despite of this, the response time is too high, about 20 - 30 seconds (this time depends on the specified query params)

Any help is useful!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I changed the find params, replacing these by real data.

The above query takes 46 seconds, and this is the information given by explain() function:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor timestamp_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 124494,
    "nscannedObjects" : 124494,
    "nscanned" : 124494,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 124494,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 124494,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 45,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 46338,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "timestamp" : [
            [
                1380520800000,
                1380558200000
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ip-XXXXXXXX:27017"
}
```

Comment: If your intention is Geo-Location queries somewhere down the track you might want to consider a different document structure. But aside from that, your query looks more theoretical than real ( as timestamp values clearly do not fall in the range you are specifying ) and theoretical questions rarely get meaningful answers. There are also a lot of variables involved here in a "10 million record" query that are far to broad to cover unless you can be more specific. Please try and present a very specific case.

Comment: I agree your search itself is getting 124K records which does not make much scope of improvement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The explain-output couldn't be more ideal. You found 124,494 documents via index (`nscanned`) and they all were valid results, so they all were returned (`n`). It still wasn't an index-only query, because the bounds weren't exact values found in specific documents.

The reason why this query is a bit slow could be the huge amount of data it returned. All the documents you found must be read from hard-drive (when the collection is cold), scanned, serialized, sent to the client via network and deserialized by the client.

Do you really need that much data for your use-case? When the answer is yes, does responsiveness really matter? I do not know what kind of application you actually want to create, but I am wildly guessing that yours is one of three use-cases:

1. You want to show all that data in form of some kind of report. That would mean the output would be a huge list the user has to scroll through. In that case I would recommend to use pagination. Only load as much data as fits on one screen and provide `next` and `previous` buttons. MongoDB pagination can be done with the cursor methods `.limit(n)` and `.skip(n)`.
2. The above, but it is some kind of offline-report the user can download and then examine with all kinds of data-mining tools. In that case the initial load-time would be acceptable, because the user will spend some time with the data they received.
3. You don't want to show all of that raw-data to the user but process it and present it in some kind of aggregated way, like a statistic or a diagram. In that case you could likely do all that work already on the database with the aggregation framework.

Comment: @user1503117 how you are using pagination and making the queries faster? Can you please explain?

Comment: I have to compare data from mongo and mysql. Both data are around 500,000 rows, and I'm using python for the actual compare. Data in mongo colelction has increased by a lot now, and select by timestamp even with index is taking ~10 mins. Any way to decrease that time?

Comment: @Rahul you might want to ask that as a new question where you exactly describe what you want to do and how you do it.

Comment: try sharding to increase efficiency of this, it'll improve it definitely.